# How to change delimiter in the exported data in Hybris?

Tags: delimiter, sap-commerce-cloud, data-export, impex, hybris-data-hub

I am exporting data from SAP Hybris.
The data I am importing also has semicolons (;).
In the exported data I see the delimiter is ; This is preventing me from splitting the data and do my work. Is there a way to change this delimiter to something else ?

I understand this can be achieved by changing the "csv.fieldseparator" property, but that would affect everywhere and I can't afford that in production.. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to use ` ` ?

Comment: @SebastianCăşvean I am sorry I don't follow. Are you suggesting to surround the data with quotes ? I am exporting the data, do we have an option to add quotes around the data before exporting ?

Comment: My mistake, I'm sorry. I thought that you want to import data which contains ";". Do you use `hac` to export your data ?

Comment: @SebastianCăşvean Yes hac

Comment: Ok and where do you use the exported data ? What is the problem with the ";" ? Don't you export it in a `.csv` file ?

Comment: The issue is the data fields I export also has ; in it. So when I try to split the data and do what I need, I am facing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to *backoffice*.
2. Search *export*.
3. In the advanced configurations set your new *delimiter*. *By default,
   it is semi-colon (;)*.

[image: Sample backoffice advanced export configuration]

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary: No worries man. If you found it useful you can accept my answer. Thanks.